# Magento stuck on " It's time to change your password."

Tags: php, magento, passwords, magento2, change-password

I didn't use Magento 2.0.2.0 CE for about 1 month. After that I logged in to admin after, opened my account/Account information page, the title “It's time to change your password.” was shown. When I tried to open my products (or settings page), the similar page “It's time to change your password.” was shown

I changed my password and pressed “Save Account”. And nothing changed, I still see “It's time to change your password.”, all menu items lead to this page “It's time to change your password.”

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to clear browser cache?

Comment: yes, but it doesn't help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) Run this `SQL` script in your store db:
 `UPDATE admin_passwords SET expires = <<some future timestamp>> WHERE user_id = <<admin_user_id>>;`

- i have used `<<some future timestamp>>` = 1999999998
- `<<admin_user_id>>` - you can find your user id in the table
  `admin_user`

Also you can make the same job with help of some UI client: just edit `expires` column in    `admin_passwords` table to 1999999998 (i suggest to change all lines to affect all users):
[image: db client]

2) Clean your browser cache and coockie.

3) Login to Magento. Enjoy it!

Answer (score 23):

**Run commands in the magento root instead of changing to database:**

Disable force password change and password lifetime

```
php bin/magento config:set admin/security/password_is_forced 0
php bin/magento config:set admin/security/password_lifetime 0
```

Reindex and Clean the cache

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento c:c
```

Answer (score 7):

Just run following sql query if path `admin/security/password_is_forced` exist

```
UPDATE `core_config_data` SET `value` = '0' WHERE `path` = 'admin/security/password_is_forced';
```

else

```
INSERT INTO `core_config_data` (`config_id`, `scope`, `scope_id`, `path`, `value`) VALUES (NULL, 'default', '0', 'admin/security/password_is_forced', '0');
```

Answer (score 5):

Here are the steps to fix this problem so it does not appear again.

1. Update expires value in table admin_passwords
   Run bellow sql query in PhpMyAdmin:

   `UPDATE admin_passwords SET expires = 1999999998 WHERE user_id = <<admin_user_id>>;`
2. change **Password Change** to **Recommended** in **Stores > Configuration > ADVANCED > Admin > Security** section

   See more detail at https://bestcodestore.com/magento-2-issue-time-change-password/

Answer (score 2):

Run below commands in the Magento root directory from CLI

```
php bin/magento config:set admin/security/password_is_forced 0
php bin/magento config:set admin/security/password_lifetime 0
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else who gets this after upgrading to Magento 2.4.3 or above.
We had the same issue. Fix for us was:
Temporarily disable forced passwords

```
php bin/magento config:set admin/security/password_is_forced 0
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

In the MAP we had to go to:
Stores > Config > Advanced | System > Security
Set **Max Session Size in Admin** to `0`
This gave a warning, but saved fine.
Then flushed cache.

We could then re-enable force password change

```
php bin/magento config:set admin/security/password_is_forced 1
```

or
Stores > Config > Advanced | Admin > Security
Set **Password Change** to `Forced`
Then flush cache.

Answer (score -1):

I followed burzhuy's suggestion - but instead of running the script I opened the database table "admin_passwords" through phpMyAdmin. This table wasn't available in the early versions of Magento 2.
If you have only very few users/admins, just chance the UNIX TimeStamp by copy/paste to something in the far future. There is a number of time stamp converters on the internet.

It's still necessary to clear browser cache and cookies after this database update. Works perfectly.

IMO this should only be recommended for developing purposes and goes rather against all password safety rules.

Comment: in general you did the same job as i described but, via UI.